# retrieve HTTP requests and responses with prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I need to retrieve the raw HTTP data for my application using prometheus , i don't want metrics but the actual raw data. is this something doable with prometheus ? or does it only handle metrics over the raw data ?

```
http.request.method: The HTTP request method (GET, POST, etc.).
http.request.uri: The URI targeted by the HTTP request.
http.request.version: The HTTP version used in the request.
http.request.full_uri: The full URI of the HTTP request.
http.response.code: The HTTP response status code.
http.user_agent: The User-Agent header field in HTTP requests.
http.content_length_header: The Content-Length header field in HTTP requests/responses.
http.content_type: The Content-Type header field in HTTP requests/responses.
http.cookie: The Cookie header field in HTTP requests.
http.host: The Host header field in HTTP requests.
http.referer: The Referer header field in HTTP requests.
http.location: The Location header field in HTTP responses.
http.authorization: The Authorization header field in HTTP requests.
http.connection: The Connection header field in HTTP requests.
```

I tried dynatrace and could find this data but could not find an API to retrieve it nor export it from UI. now i'am looking at Prometeus as an alternative solution

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus is specialized on metrics data: you can only scrape/store/query data that represents metrics.

For traces there is [Grafana Tempo](https://grafana.com/oss/tempo/).

Alternatively, what you shown in the question looks somewhat like loggable data. Maybe [Grafana Loki](https://grafana.com/oss/loki/) (Like Prometheus, but for logs) can help you.